# how to echo image using DOMDocument

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

How to print `url` from `img src`?

if that looping the code is like this

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $link) {
        echo $link->getAttribute('src');
        echo "<br />";
}
```

But I don't want to use looping, I am only want to show the first `img src`

here what I try

```
<?php
$content = html_entity_decode ("asdasdasdasdasdasdasdasasdasdasdasdasdasdasd&lt;img src=&quot;http://asdasd.video/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/rsz_nanatsu.jpg&quot;&gt;");

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);

echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->getAttribute('src')->item(0);

?>
```

**Result :** `http://asdasd.video/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/rsz_nanatsu.jpg`

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The code is printing exactly the same output as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `item()` at the wrong place. The short form is :

```
echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('img')->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
```

A better code should be :

```
$items = $dom->getElementsByTagName('img');
if ($items->length > 0) {
    echo $items->item(0)->getAttribute('src');
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I've made some errors. It's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a **break** statement at the end of the loop:

```
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $link) {
    echo $link->getAttribute('src');
    echo "<br />";
    break;
}
```